# Is Php + Java an insane idea or could it be a good choice?

Tags: java, php

I've been working on web apps for a while now, using php and then Java. Of course I prefere coding in Java, it gives more flexibility, performance and lots of professional components and libraries. But I don't like JSPs very much, PHP was more easy if only limited to front-end and simple Controller functionalities, moreover, PHP is well accepted by designers. So I'm thinking of using Php for View + Some simple controller tasks and Java for the rest of controller code + model. To implement this I would use apache for php and tomcat for J2EE stuff.

What do you think, is this an unnecessary waste of resources? Or does it make sense? How would you bridge the two?

Comment: So you prefer coding in Java, however due to the fact that PHP is accepted by designers (I wonder where you got that information, can you share it?), you'd want to use both and double your coding for no apparent reason?

Comment: So PHP would have to talk to the Java controllers via HTTP, since Java and PHP can't directly call each other... You'd spent probably 99% of your app's time on HTTP overhead and have the response time of a glacier running a marathon, compared to the same app coded purely in one or the other language.

Comment: ... why exactly don't you like JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can appreciate why you would want to try this. JSP is one my least favorite technologies for building a web page, and I've been using it for a decade now. The easiest way to implement what you are looking for is to code up all your Java controllers as web services and invoke them from your PHP code. I would recommend using JSON as the data interchange as the parsing will be faster. Alternatively, you could take a look at some technologies that combine Java and PHP in interesting ways:

PHP/Java Bridge - http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/how_it_works.php
Quercus - http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/

Zend also includes Java support in their server offering. You can read more on their product page.

Answer (score 4):

If you like how PHP works as far as the front-end goes, try out [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).

Answer (score 4):

I think I would go with it being a waste of resources - and I'm no particular fan of PHP.

Contrary to what some developers believe you can write well-structured and easily maintainable PHP websites/web-apps - it's not as hard as you think and it would probably be a better idea than what you intend.

Consider using one of the many excellent PHP MVC frameworks such as [Cake](http://cakephp.org/) or [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) and perhaps introduce some good third party libraries such as the Zend Framework. If you have time then take a look at the source code for SugarCRM which (unless its went downhill in the last few years) is an excellent example of a well structured PHP web-app.

Answer (score 4):

On a side note, have you looked at Apache's [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)? It may make some of the front end developing a little better. It allows you to create the UI basically with just straight html. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like JSP as the view layer technology for Java web applications, there are plenty of other choices for template engines that you can use instead. For example:

- [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/)
- [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/)

Velocity is an excellent tool IMHO and the company I work for uses it in our webapps far more often than we use JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

I use both Java and PHP in my daily work, but I've never mixed them as you suggest. I can't really see how it will make an application better, and even though it makes sense to you it probably won't make sense to any other programmer who might end up maintaining your code at some point in the future.

I use PHP for web development due to the fact that PHP has one of the highest "market shares". There's a wide range of CMS systems you can use to develop upon. I like to use Drupal myself, due to the fact that everything that has to do with session handling, user management, database connections and a lot more already is taken care of. All i need to do is to develop a new module. Some might say that Drupal is overkill for small solutions, but I'd say that the user won't notice the difference and you'll save oceans of development time.

I'd stick to the true and tried technology combos!